# How to enable the Play Store App in my platform build for Pixel 3?

Tags: android, build, store, android-source, platform

I tried to build the AOSP platform for a Google Pixel 3 phone.
To do that, I downloaded the AOSP platform source for Pixel 3 from the Google Server.
I did not modified anything in the AOSP platform source tree and just performed the build.
It took about 12 hours and done successfully.

Using fastboot, I flashed the built images to my Pixel 3 phone and it worked!
My Pixel 3 boots successfully and works OK.
However, I can't find the Play Store App now.
Did I miss something during the build procedure?

Or should I pass the compatibility test (CTS) to get the Play Store App?
Is it required to take the CTS test even if I build the AOSP platform just for private usage?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play services are not part of standard AOSP.

Yes, you need to pass CTS and get kind of licensed, and then you can get access to those.

You could also get them manually from here: https://opengapps.org/ , I thinks that's OK for private usage, not sure about the legality of distributing them.